# Ubuntu, How do I see a log of logins made?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to see who has logged into a system via SSH, from which IP and when.

The system is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS , so there is no /var/log/secure

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check in `/var/log/auth.log`
There is no /var/log/secure in Ubuntu -- afaik (that was RedHat?).

Also, remember [log rotation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Log_Rotation) (so, lookup the `auth.log.N.gz` files too).

more ref.

1. [LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) at Ubuntu Help pages describe [auth.log](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Authorization_Log) -- has a lot more details
2. [20 Linux Log Files that are Located under /var/log Directory](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/linux-var-log-files/).

Answer (score 6):

The command "last" will show you login history.

Answer (score 4):

Check out `lastlog` :

```
petrus@host:~$ lastlog 
Utilisateur      Port     Venant de        Dernière
root                                       **Jamais connecté**
daemon                                     **Jamais connecté**
bin                                        **Jamais connecté**
sys                                        **Jamais connecté**
petrus           pts/0    2a01:e34:ee8c:18 dim. juin 17 20:06:14 +0200 2012
```

Comment: Sorry, system is in french, but it says: "User", "From", and "Last login". "Jamais connecté" means "never logged in".